# Why in F# you can write String.Join but not string.Join?

Tags: f#

In C# you can write `string.Join` and `String.Join`. But in F# you cannot write string.Join but only String.Join. Why is that? Is not string a type alias over .NET String class?

Answer (score 11):

In F# `string`, depending on where it's used, is a type alias *or* a function:

```
string 12 // this stringifies '12'

let f (s: string) = ... // here 'string' is a type alias for 'System.String'
```

And so static members like `Join` don't sit on `string`. They are available via `String`. If you created your own alias, then you'd get access to the static members via `.`.

In C#, both `string` and `String` refer to the same `System.String` at all times.

Comment: `let somethingToString (x:string []) = string.Join(" ",x)` is not legal F# although string here is used as a type alias not as a function.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's because `string` as-used there is the `string` function. There's no way to do what you're looking for here without just doing `String.`